# How to drive up to millions of ws2812 or APA104 LEDs?

Tags: ws2812b, ws2811, pixels

I've driven more than 2k of APA102 from a computer using a USB to SPI interface for an interactive project.
Since then I've been curious how I could made the same setup for even a large pixel area, up to a million or more pixels from a computer.

Definitely it wouldn't be with USB-something interface and it would probably require output from a Ethernet connection (similar to the sending and receiving card of a display screen matrix).

What drivers exist on the market to accomplish this kind of setup?
Maybe it would require a fpga to parallelize the output data.

I'm looking for a commercial ready solution mostly.

Edit
Looks like [Pixblasters](https://www.crowdsupply.com/pixblasters/video-led-controller) can do exactly what I'm asking for, but is not yet available.

Answer (score 1):

A high-definition (1080p30) video stream represents about 1.5 Gb/s of data.

Commercial video walls (a.k.a. "Jumbotron") are built up from [edge-stackable modules](https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/led-video-wall-module.html) (anywhere from 1000 to 10,000 LEDs per module) that are typically networked together using Ethernet. A master controller receives a video stream over any standard connection (HDMI, etc.), and then formats the data to send to the individual modules using a proprietary protocol.

Obviously, there are many ways to produce HDMI video from computers, disk players, etc.

Comment: That was what I was refering to on my post: _similar to the sending and receiving card of a display screen matrix_. But obviously that solution is not made for addressable LED.

I'm looking for a go to ready solution.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the APA102 instead of the WS2812 or APA104.  It uses a synchronous protocol which allows it to be controlled from an SPI perhipheral at high data rates.  What you use to drive them will depend significantly on the "content" you plan to display, update rate, etc.  An FPGA is certainly one valid option. Depending on the physical size of the "display" you are trying to build, you may also need to consider signal integrity over long distances.

[APA102](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14016)

Comment: Already used an USB-SPI interface for more than 2K APA102. But you are still very limited for bandwidth using this solution.